# Scala Play Framework - getting "cannot enqueue after timer shutdown" error when running tests that involve Akka

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, mockito, playframework-2.4

When trying to unit test my code (with Mockito) that runs an Akka scheduler I keep getting "cannot enqueue after timer shutdown".

My code:

**Global.scala**

```
override def onStart(app: Application){
    Some(Akka.system.scheduler.schedule(23.hours, 24.hours) {
         println("I run all the time")
    })
}
```

**TasksRepositorySpec.scala**

```
def insertTestData() = {
    running(FakeApplication()) {
       //some code
    }
}
```

When I run:

```
activator test
```

I get:

```
[info] TasksRepositorySpec
[info] 
[error] ! 
[error]  cannot enqueue after timer shutdown (Scheduler.scala:270)
[error] akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler.schedule(Scheduler.scala:270)
[error] akka.actor.Scheduler$class.schedule(Scheduler.scala:79)
[error] akka.actor.LightArrayRevolverScheduler.schedule(Scheduler.scala:182)
[error] Global$.onStart(Global.scala:56)
[error] play.api.GlobalPlugin.onStart(GlobalSettings.scala:272)
[error] play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
[error] play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
[error] play.api.Plugins.foreach(Plugins.scala:57)
[error] play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply$mcV$sp(Play.scala:91)
[error] play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
[error] play.api.Play$$anonfun$start$1.apply(Play.scala:91)
[error] play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:21)
[error] play.api.Play$.start(Play.scala:90)
[error] play.api.test.PlayRunners$class.running(Helpers.scala:41)
[error] play.api.test.Helpers$.running(Helpers.scala:363)
[error] repositories.TasksRepositorySpec.insertData(TasksRepositorySpec.scala:69)
[error] repositories.TasksRepositorySpec$$anonfun$2.apply$mcI$sp(TasksRepositorySpec.scala:88)
[error] repositories.TasksRepositorySpec$$anonfun$2.apply(TasksRepositorySpec.scala:88)
[error] repositories.TasksRepositorySpec$$anonfun$2.apply(TasksRepositorySpec.scala:88)
```

I use play 2.4

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Same issue here under Play 2.3

Comment: I actually use play 2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I didn't find a solution, but only a workaround. It consists in using a fake `Global` object for tests where `onStart()` and `onStop()` methods are empty.

First you need to split your `Global` object into a trait and an empty object:

**Global.scala**

```
object Global extends Global

trait Global extends GlobalSettings { ... }
```

Then in your test code, you can create a fake `Global`:

**Fake.scala**

```
object FakeGlobal extends Global {
  override def onStart(app: Application): Unit = {}
  override def onStop(app: Application): Unit = {}
}

object Fake {
  // This has to be a method, cannot be a value
  def application() = FakeApplication(withGlobal = Some(FakeGlobal))
}
```

And finally use it in your tests:

**TasksRepositorySpec.scala**

```
def insertTestData() = {
  running(Fake.application()) {
    //some code
  }
}
```

It works for me. Hope it helps!